# Tcl error while installing Wordnet

Tags: software-installation, tcl

While installing Wordnet, I'm getting the following error;

> stubs.c:132:14: error: ‘Tcl_Interp’ has no member named ‘result’

I tried giving following;

```
#define USE_INTERP_RESULT 1
```

at the end of "config.c" file of the Wordnet. Then als its not working. Kindly help.

Comment: Mention the way you tried to install it and your system for better help. (Now with "add comment")

Comment: I found it much trouble to deal with Tcl/Tk, so rewrote the make to produce simple cmdline window: https://github.com/AncientZygote/WNtight

Answer (score 10):

In the `stubs.c` file (which will be found in the `WordNet-3.0/src`directory include the following directive

```
#define USE_INTERP_RESULT 1
```

before the `#include <tcl.h>`

and the do the make

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that you try to compile Wordnet with Tcl 8.6.

Tcl 8.5 deprecated `interp->result` and Tcl 8.6 removed it.

The directive

```
#define USE_INTERP_RESULT
```

should solve that, but you should add that in an header file (`.h`) before you `#include <tcl.h>`, not in a `.c` file.

Comment: Thanks for your solution.                                        I gave #define USE_INTERP_RESULT 1                              1. In tk.h file in the tk installation directory before tcl.h inclusion                                                        2.In tk.h of the Wordnet include directory before tcl.h inclusion.                                                       Then also i'm facing the same error

Comment: I am ble to resolve the error. I gave  #define USE_INTERP_RESULT 1 in the stubs.c of WordNet3.0/src